# RestKit relationship faults

Tags: ios, restkit

I have a problem with the communication between objects. I get on the api json string and is divided into objects in restkit. Sometimes I'm getting tied objects, and sometimes not. I have an object thematics, which is part of the object articles and sometimes I get thematics, and sometimes not.

Articles.h

```
#import "Article.h"
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface Article (CoreDataProperties)
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *count;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *dateCreate;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *dateJournal;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *imagePath;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *likes;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *localTop;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *objectId;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *pressed;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *text;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *top;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *type_cell;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *url;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<Author *> *authors;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<Thematic *> *thematics;
@end
@interface Article (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addAuthorsObject:(Author *)value;
- (void)removeAuthorsObject:(Author *)value;
- (void)addAuthors:(NSSet<Author *> *)values;
- (void)removeAuthors:(NSSet<Author *> *)values;
- (void)addThematicsObject:(Thematic *)value;
- (void)removeThematicsObject:(Thematic *)value;
- (void)addThematics:(NSSet<Thematic *> *)values;
- (void)removeThematics:(NSSet<Thematic *> *)values;
@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Thematic.h

```
#import "Thematic.h"
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface Thematic (CoreDataProperties)
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *objectId;
@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

MappingProvider.h

```
+(RKMapping *) articlesMapping {
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Article" inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"id":@"objectId", @"title":@"title", @"text":@"text", @"date_create":@"dateCreate",@"likes":@"likes",@"avatar":@"imagePath", @"pressed":@"pressed", @"subtitle":@"subtitle",@"url":@"url",@"count":@"count",@"top":@"top",@"local_top":@"localTop"}];
mapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"objectId"];
[mapping addPropertyMapping:
 [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"thematics"
                                             toKeyPath:@"thematics"
                                           withMapping:[self thematicsMapping]]
 ];
[mapping addPropertyMapping:
 [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"authors"
                                             toKeyPath:@"authors"
                                           withMapping:[self authorsMapping]]
 ];
return mapping;
```

}

```
+ (RKMapping *) thematicsMapping {
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Thematic" inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id":@"objectId", @"name": @"name" }];
mapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"objectId"];
return mapping;
```

}

The fact that the thematics I get on the network, but restkit writes thematics relationship faults.

[image]

JSON example

```
{
"id": 104,
"title": "test message",
"url": "test message",
"subtitle": "test message",
"top": 1,
"status": 1,
"thematics": [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "photo"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Please also show the data and the log

Comment: @ybbaigo update json example

Comment: people please help! i cant resolve this problem ((((